# How to create CTE which uses another CTE as the data to further limit?

Tags: sql, common-table-expression

I have searched this question here but couldn't find it, please redirect me if we already have it on the site.

I'm looking for a way to create CTE which uses another CTE as the data to further limit. I have a CTE which creates a report for me , but I would like to narrow this report with  another input using the existing CTE.

I hope my question is clear.

Comment: Which SQL dialect is this?

Comment: The one that I'm using is dialect 3

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can chain 2 (or more) CTE's together.

For example

```sql
with ObjectsWithA as
(
  select * from sys.objects
  where name like '%A%'
),
ObjectsWithALessThan100 as
(
  select * from ObjectsWithA
  where object_id < 100
)
select * from ObjectsWithALessThan100;
```

Or the same example, with more "spelled out" names/aliases:

```sql
with ObjectsWithA (MyObjectId , MyObjectName) as
(
  select object_id as MyObjIdAlias , name as MyNameAlias 
  from sys.objects
  where name like '%A%'
),
ObjectsWithALessThan100 as
(
  select * from ObjectsWithA theOtherCte
  where theOtherCte.MyObjectId < 100
)
select lessThan100Alias.MyObjectId , lessThan100Alias.MyObjectName 
from ObjectsWithALessThan100 lessThan100Alias 
order by lessThan100Alias.MyObjectName;
```

Comment: I hadn't originally been putting a comma between my CTE statements, so i was getting a traceback. This worked.

Answer (score 13):

A CTE can refer to previous CTEs:

```
with report as (
      <your query here>
     ),
     reportLimited as (
      select *
      from report
      where foo = @bar
    )
select *
from reportLimited
```

The only rule is that the references have to be sequential.  No forward references.

Answer (score 7):

Sure, just reference the CTE directly:

```
WITH Source As
( 
  SELECT * FROM AllData
),
Filtered AS
(
  SELECT * FROM Source WHERE ID = 4
)
SELECT * FROM Filtered
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH 
Source ---------1--------- 
As
( 
    SELECT * FROM emp
),
destination----2----------
AS
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM Source 
    WHERE E_id = 4
)

SELECT * FROM destination
```

Comment: While your answer may solve the question, it is always better if you can provide a description of what the issue was and how your answer solves it. This is a suggestion for further improving this and future answers.

Comment: @sangu patil: I can't see any difference between this one and other couple given answers! Before you posted your answer, please make sure it has not already posted! Otherwise, it is just being a "flood" and makes other people find the alternatives harder.