# I am having problems in constructing a CTE with two existing CTEs in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, join, syntax, common-table-expression

I am solving a problem from: https://platform.stratascratch.com/coding/10314-revenue-over-time?python&utm_source=youtube&utm_medium=click&utm_campaign=YT+description+link only with the little knowledge that I have of sql (I started a few days ago). With that said, it is safe to say my approach is far from good, but since I am still getting used to this, can anyone tell me what type of error I am getting and how to fix it? I believe to have followed the general syntax shown here: [How to create CTE which uses another CTE as the data to further limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17032293/how-to-create-cte-which-uses-another-cte-as-the-data-to-further-limit) , but I want to use a full join on top of that. The first link provided above can run the code written below.

```
with cte_amz_purchases(purch_date, purch_amt) 
    as 
    (select created_at, sum(purchase_amt) from amazon_purchases 
        group by created_at order by created_at),
    cte_date_range(date_purchased)
    as
    (SELECT date_trunc('day', dd):: date as date_purchased
        FROM generate_series ( '2020-01-01' ::timestamp, '2020-10-24'::timestamp, '1 day'::interval) dd),
    cte_DailyAmt()
    as
    (select date_purchased, coalesce(cte_amz_purchases.purch_amt,0) as purch_amt from cte_amz_purchases full join cte_date_range on cte_amz_purchases.purch_date=cte_date_range.date_purchased)

select * from cte_DailyAmt;
```

**EDIT**
It appears the problem is inherent to the platform. The code works in my local machine just fine. Apologies to anyone who wasted their time looking into this question.

Comment: The comma should come before the CTE name, correct? I think I have those commas right where they should be...? The first one after "order by created_at)" and the next one should come after "'1 day'::interval) dd)"...?

Comment: Ah, you are right. The formatting confused me.

Comment: Sorry about the formatting! :)